# Resources for programming a system that supports plugins

Tags: java, c, plugins, extensibility

I need resources -preferably a text-  about programming systems that supports plugins or extensibility and other related detailed stuff, like handling permissions and resources for those plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) ?

Comment: looks very very good
I  started reading the specification
thanks